# How to open content of a file in MDI subwindow from treeview

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have opened the file from the current directory in "opened" method, here file is opening and reading the data in it, but I want to write the read data in MDI `subwindow`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import QMenu
import os
import tree2

class fileview(tree2.Ui_FOSApplication,QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(fileview, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_view)
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        path = 'C:\FOS Application'
        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(path))
        #self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.context_view)
        #self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setColumnHidden(1, True)
        self.treeView.setColumnHidden(2, True)
        self.treeView.setColumnHidden(3, True)

    def context_view(self):
        view = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        open = view.addAction("Open")
        open.triggered.connect(self.subwindow)
        curser = QtGui.QCursor()
        view.exec_(curser.pos())

    def subwindow(self):
        fileview.count = fileview.count+1
        self.w = self.openfile()
        self.sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        self.sub.setWidget(self.w)
        #self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow(self.sub)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.sub)
        self.sub.show()

    def openfile(self):
        index = self.treeView.currentIndex()
        file_name = self.model.filePath(index)
        os.startfile(file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])`enter code here`
    fb = fileview()
    fb.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What "same content"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.